# what is the purpose of the EnableSwagger routeTemplate parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm trying to solve an issue where my controllers are decorated with a RoutePrefix like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}/users")]
```

But Swagger displays the urls in the TOC like this:

```
/api/v{version}/users/search
```

I was experimenting with the EnableSwagger routeTemplate parameter but I ended up getting the errors displayed in the inline comments below:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .EnableSwagger(
    //"v{version:apiVersion}",  //A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
    //"v{version}",             //Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:52056/v{version}
    //"{version}",              //Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:52056/{version}
    //"v2",                     //Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:52056/v2
    c =>
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

What is the proper usage of the EnableSwagger routeTemplate parameter?  And what type of use case scenarios is this parameter designed to address?  Is this parameter designed to assist with the particular problem I described?  Or am I attempting to use this parameter incorrectly or improperly?

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding, it's to allow customization of the routes to not be defined by the traditional ASP.NET MVC/Web API route configs, like so :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

While you might find something like the above in a `WebApiConfig.cs` file, you can change the path for Swagger JSON endpoints using the `RouteTemplate`.

From the Readme :

> By default, Swagger JSON will be exposed at the following route -
>   "/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json". If necessary, you can change
>   this when enabling the Swagger middleware. Custom routes MUST include
>   the {documentName} parameter.

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
    c.RouteTemplate = "api-docs/{documentName}/swagger.json";
});
```

> NOTE: If you're using the SwaggerUI middleware, you'll also need to update its configuration to reflect the new endpoints:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/api-docs/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
})
```

For versioning APIs, you can write a custom resolver most likely. And to that point, I think you've made it a little harder on yourself by versioning your APIs this way. If you simply created a `v1/{resource}` and `v2/{resource}` you could certainly write a custom resolver to look at the version in the route and use the `c.MultipleApiVersions()` API to wire everything up according to the route.